# Mark a Commerce Order as Paid, via a custom plugin

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, payment

Checkout / Payment is being handled entirely by a 3rd Party. What would be the correct process to mark an Order as Paid via a custom Craft plugin?

The Order will already have been converted from a Cart to an Order and assigned an Order Status via a previous step.

The 3rd Party will be calling a series of API endpoints exposed by a custom Craft plugin to process the various steps of the Order.

EDIT: For future reference, base on Luke's answer below, this is the code I got to work...

```
$orderNumber = "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX";

$order = craft()->commerce_orders->getOrderByNumber($orderNumber);

$transaction = craft()->commerce_transactions->createTransaction($order);

$transaction->status = Commerce_TransactionRecord::STATUS_SUCCESS;
$transaction->type = Commerce_TransactionRecord::TYPE_PURCHASE;

craft()->commerce_transactions->saveTransaction($transaction);

craft()->commerce_orders->updateOrderPaidTotal($order);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet would be to create a transaction for the full amount:

```
$transaction = Plugin::getInstance()->transactions->createTransaction($order);
$transaction->status = \craft\commerce\records\Transaction::STATUS_SUCCESS;
$transaction->type = \craft\commerce\records\Transaction::TYPE_PURCHASE;
Plugin::getInstance()->transactions->saveTransaction($transaction);
$order->updateOrderPaidTotal();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Luke. Where you say `Plugin::getInstance()->transactions->createTransaction($order)` does that translate to `craft()->commerce_transactions->createTransaction($order)`? If so, then it all works fine.

Comment: Based on your answer, I've updated my question with the working code. Is there anything in there I shouldn't be doing, or does that look about right to you? It all seems to be working as far as I can tell.

Comment: Yes looks good!

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is interested, here's Commerce 3 version.

```
$number = 'xxx'; 
$order =  \craft\commerce\elements\Order::find()->number($number)->one();

$transaction = \craft\commerce\Plugin::getInstance()->getTransactions()->createTransaction($order);
$transaction->status = \craft\commerce\records\Transaction::STATUS_SUCCESS;
$transaction->type = \craft\commerce\records\Transaction::TYPE_PURCHASE;
\craft\commerce\Plugin::getInstance()->getTransactions()->saveTransaction($transaction);

$order->updateOrderPaidInformation();
```